# Jquery .hover on link

Tags: jquery, hover, href, jquery-hover

I try to call .increase-size on link whith Jquery but nothing happen on .a, other class works. Somebody know why ?

```
$('.et_pb_button, #cursor-button, .toggle-sub-menu, .a').hover(function(){
$('.cursor2,.cursor1').toggleClass('increase-size');
});
```

Comment: The JS in the question works fine in isolation: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/5xg1me8a. If it's not working for you please edit the question to include all the relevant HTML & CSS

Comment: In addition, note that it would be much better practice to achieve this effect using CSS alone, assuming that the HTML structure of the relevant elements allows for a valid selector to be used.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. I'll try this :) @RoryMcCrossan